# Imbalance in multi class classification problem - four target levels

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, classification, imbalanced-data, smote

I am having imbalance in my data as shown below, Whenever I have tried with ADASYN it shows error, Do we need to provide any parameter entry for the same ? Some time it runs for long time but no response even after 40 minutes of code run.

```
                     counts  percentage
Enquiry Assigned      91284   75.902382
Test Drive Provided   25274   21.015258
Test Drive Arranged    3434    2.855361
Booked                  266    0.221178
Test Ride Provided        7    0.005820
```

Please suggest how We can go ahead with the python code to solve the problem. From others recommendation I heard like

1. Can do sampling between two levels at once and then can do iteration on the same
2. Downsamplig the one with 75% may be helpful ?
3. or any solutions by using skmultilearn ?

Code:

```
def makeOverSamplesADASYN(X,y):

    #X →Independent Variable in DataFrame\
     #y →dependent Variable in Pandas DataFrame format
     from imblearn.over_sampling import ADASYN 
     sm = ADASYN(sampling_strategy='all', random_state=None, n_neighbors=5, n_jobs=1, ratio=None)
    
     X_adassin, y_adassin = sm.fit_resample(X, y)

 makeOverSamplesADASYN(X,data_dummyvar['Sales Stage'])

 print(X_adassin.shape)
 print(y_adassin.shape)'''
```

o/p=== > This runs very long time and no result after that , please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downsampled the top entries once using the below code.

```
### " data_dummyvar " is my dataframe with the shape of (120265, 894)

df_majority=data_dummyvar[data_dummyvar['Sales Stage']=='Enquiry Assigned']
df_majority.shape
from sklearn.utils import resample

# Downsample majority class
df_majority_downsampled = resample(df_majority,replace=False,n_samples=25289,random_state=123)                                   
#replace: sample without replacement
# n_samples: to match minority class
#random_state: reproducible results
df_majority_downsampled.shape
df_minority=data_dummyvar[data_dummyvar['Sales Stage'] !='Enquiry Assigned']
df_minority['Sales Stage'].value_counts()
df_first_scaling = pd.concat([df_majority_downsampled,df_minority],ignore_index=True)
g = df_first_scaling['Sales Stage']
df = pd.concat([g.value_counts(),              
g.value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)],axis=1, keys=('counts','percentage'))
print (df)
```

The above code will give result as below: o/p ===>>

```
                        counts  percentage
Enquiry Assigned      25289   46.598489
Test Drive Provided   25281   46.583748
Test Drive Arranged    3434    6.327621
Booked                  266    0.490142
```

the 'Enquiry Assigned' entries are down sampled here now.

Now We need to run SMOTE/ADASYN kind of algorithm to our data " df_first_scaling " two time since We have three more entries as shown below

```
def makeOverSamplesADASYN(X,y):
   #input DataFrame
   #X →Independent Variable in DataFrame\
   #y →dependent Variable in Pandas DataFrame format
   from imblearn.over_sampling import ADASYN 
   sm = ADASYN(sampling_strategy='minority', random_state=None, n_neighbors=5, n_jobs=1, ratio=None)
   global X_adassin_1
   global y_adassin_1
   X_adassin_1, y_adassin_1 = sm.fit_resample(X, y)

makeOverSamplesADASYN(X,df_first_scaling['Sales Stage']) # function call

print(X_adassin_1.shape)
print(y_adassin_1.shape)
```

This gives o/p which is shape as==>

```
(79334, 893)
(79334,)
```

After running the same again over the updated data set We can get sample df with the shape of (101229, 893)  & (101229,)